# SocketTimeoutException not thrown

Tags: java, android, sockets

I try to handle the situation when the networking is temporarily lost either on client side or server side, and in order to do that, I've used `setSoTimeout()` method on client side. (Server side is written in other language)

My client scheme is the following:

1.the client sends pings to server every 1 second,

2.timeout is set to 2 seconds, hence `readLine()` is supposed to throw exception if no data is received after 2 seconds of blocking

After implementing this, I tried the following scenario:

-I launch the program

-client sends pings every second, server properly receives them and replies back. so far so good,

-now I suddenly turn off server's wifi. server waits for pings and closes the socket after 2 seconds

-however client is still blocked in `readLine()`, although it is supposed to throw `SocketTimeoutException` when more than 2 seconds elapsed since last ping reply (just like server did)

Then I changed the client scheme a bit, and set timeout to 0.5 seconds, instead of 2

This is what happens (I don't shut down wifi this time):

-I launch the program

-first ping is sent, server receives it, and replies back

-after 0.5 seconds, `readLine()` throws `SocketTimeoutException`, socket is closed

-server closes the socket as well

The question: why no exception is thrown in first scenario, and why it is thrown in second scenario

```
Socket socket = new Socket("someaddress", someport);
socket.setSoTimeout(2000);

//writes to socket
bufferedwriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
//reads from socket
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

 new Thread(new Runnable(){

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                while(bufferedwriter!=null)
                                {

                                    try 
                                    {

                                        bufferedwriter.write("ping");
                                        bufferedwriter.flush();
                                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                                    } 
                                    catch (IOException          e) { Log.e("SPLASH", "IO Exception in pinger"); e.printStackTrace(); } 
                                    catch (InterruptedException e) { Log.e("SPLASH", "In.Exception in pinger"); e.printStackTrace(); }

                                }//end while


                            }}).start();




 new Thread(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            String msg;

                            try {
                                while((msg=in.readLine())!=null)
                                {
                                    System.out.println("user received: " + msg);




                                }//end while


                            }
                            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                        }}).start();
```

UPDATE.
Interestingly, when `in` is assigned `null` value while waiting for some message from inputstream, `SocketTimeoutException` is thrown

Comment: Show the client's code please

Comment: @KErlandsson I don't think that there is something special to see in the code : ) anyway I added the code as well